# google map info window show on random time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

How can I make on google map info window to show on random pin every 3 seconds? 
Info window shows on a pin, then closes and after 3 seconds is shown on another random pin with the informations of that pin. It's a Wordpress website. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code? You can start by checking the settimeout method in javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout for the delay...

Answer (score 0):

First store all marker objects in an array eg:- markerArray[].

Fetch a marker object randomnly from markerArray and show infowindow using setTimout function.

```
    var markerObj = markerArray[Math.floor(markerArray.length * Math.random())];

    setInterval(function () {
          // close current infowindow
          infowindow.close(); 

          // show new infowindow
          infowindow.open(map, markerObj);
    },3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Question is not clear..You are looking for code which refresh page every 3 seconds? You can use following script to refresh your page.

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/yoursite.html">
```